# Shape mismatch Value Error when attempting to fill entire row/column with specific value

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am attempting to do the following: I have a three dimensional array, X, of shape (Z, M, N). I have a separate one dimensional array, Y, of shape(M) containing integer values, where values greater than 0 represent the rows in X that I wish to set the corresponding value in Y. For example, see the following scenarios:

```
X =
[[[0. 0.]
  [0. 0.]]

 [[1. 1.]
  [1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1.]
  [1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1.]
  [1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1.]
  [1. 1.]]]
Y =
[0 1]
```

should return:

```
[[[0. 0.]
  [1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1.]
  [1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1.]
  [1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1.]
  [1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1.]
  [1. 1.]]]
```

or when `Y = [0 0]`, should return:

```
[[[0. 0.]
  [0. 0.]]

 [[1. 1.]
  [1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1.]
  [1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1.]
  [1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1.]
  [1. 1.]]]
```

The following code works for the first scenario, but raises the following error on the second scenario, which is what I cannot seem to solve. I am running this using Python 3.6.8 on Windows 10 Pro.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "blah2.py", line 41, in <module>
    r[np.where(y>0), :] = y[np.where(y>0)]
ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (0,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (1,0,2)
```

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.ones((5, 2, 2))
y = np.array([0, 0])

r = np.zeros((2,2))
r[np.where(y>0), :] = y[np.where(y>0)]
x[0] = r
print(x)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extend the indexed `y` to `2D` and then assign, so that it becomes broadcastable against indexed `x` -

```
x[0,np.where(y>0),:] = y[np.where(y>0),None]
```

Or a better way would be to simply use a `mask` and assign while extending the indexed `y` to `2D` -

```
m = y>0 # get mask of comparisons
x[0,m,:] = y[m,None]
```